# Learn Python the Hard Way Exercise 17 Extra Question(S)

Tags: python, python-2.x

I'm doing Zed Shaw's fantastic [Learn Python The Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.com/), but an extra question has me stumped: Line 9--10 could be written in one line, how? I've tried some different thoughts, but to no avail. I could move on, but what would the fun in that be?

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

script, from_file, to_file = argv

print "Copying from %s to %s" % (from_file, to_file)

# we could do these two on one line too, how?
input = open(from_file)
indata = input.read()

print "The input file is %d bytes long" % len(indata)

print "Does the output file exist? %r" % exists(to_file)
print "Ready, hit RETURN to continue, CTRL-C to abort."
raw_input()

output = open(to_file, 'w')
output.write(indata)

print "Alright, all done."
```

Zed also writes that he could do the whole script in one line. I'm not exactly sure what he means by that.

Feel free to help me however you want: by giving the answer or merely hinting---and perhaps including a collapsed or hidden answer to the question.

Comment: For more difficult expressions, you should avoid stuffing as much as possible on one line.

Comment: If you don't have any indented blocks, you can just string every line together, terminated with a semicolon.  *Very* bad form, but if you're hell-bent on it...

Comment: Or if you genuinely want to be a pain-in-the-ass: http://effbot.org/pyfaq/is-it-possible-to-write-obfuscated-one-liners-in-python.htm

Comment: Also see the discussion on author's website: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex17.html

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
indata = open(from_file).read()
```

Comment: yeah - though this (as well as the two-line solution) will leave the file open longer than needed, so you should avoid this in real code (a better way to do it in one line is `with open(from_file) as f: indata = f.read()`, if you want to save lines just for the hell of it)

Comment: This seems the closest to the Python been taught up until that exercise. I just don't see how anyone would be able to infer such a solution from a completely new background - I also know some Java, but would not have thought of something like that.

Is there a special terminology for this specific measure?

I can't figure out how someone would figure this out, but maybe the extra questions are just aimed at a higher level than I presumed.

Regardless, thanks a bunch. I would probably not have figured it out without the explicit solution. The same applies to everyone else's help.

Comment: @Kiwi You would notice that `input` is set once and used once immediately after and therefore you can remove the temporary variable by using the expression itself.

Comment: @delnan: I think the intent here is not to save lines for the "hell of it", but to get folks used to the idea of being able to chain function/method calls together like this. @Kiwi: invoking a method on an expression that returns an object is a pretty common pattern in Java too. Consider for example one (now deprecated) Java way to print the current date: "new Date().toGMTString()".

Comment: I think Python has an almost universal idea that `name1 = operation1(); name2 = name1.operation2()` will do the same thing as `name2 = operation1().operation2()`.

Answer (score 8):

[shutil](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html) is the way to do one-liner file copies in Python:

```
shutil.copy(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

Putting the `import shutil, sys` on the same line as this one (with a semicolon in-between, of course) would however be stylistically goofy;-).

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the question, though?  Usually programming tutorials focus on concepts, so answers using different concepts seem less valuable to the student.

Comment: "Less valuable" than _what_? `';'.join` of all the non-comment lines?-)

Answer (score 6):

Well you can just do "algebraic substitution," right?  ...assuming you don't care about the "UI"...

```
open(to_file, 'w').write(open(from_file).read())
```

Comment: remember `to_file = argv[2]`, etc!

Answer (score 3):

```
from sys import argv
open(argv[2], 'w').write(open(argv[1]).read())
```

Comment: This is as close as I could get too.  I suppose import statement could be on same line but I don't know how to do that yet / plus 2 lines seems good enough :)

Comment: `from sys import argv; open(argv[2], 'w').write(open(argv[1]).read())` This works fine and it's only 69 columns in a text editor.

Comment: Note from the book: `That ; depends ; on ; how ; you ; define ; one ; line ; of ; code.`

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the algebraic substitution mentioned by @dash-tom-bang.
My functioning Exercise 17 extra credit has 5 lines. The operation is being conducted on one line.

**open(to_file, 'w').write(open(from_file).read())**

followed by a simple 'print' for verification feedback

**print "File %s copied to %s" % (from_file, to_file)**

I should have a 6th line that replaces the original ''output.close'' but I am confused about how to do this without the ''output'' variable? *Ahh, since I now have no output variable there is nothing to close.*

btw- It is a little spooky for me to see the same exact line typed here that I have worked out and entered myself in gedit. Great stuff, I am really enjoying the mental challenge and community support.

Edit:answered my own question

Answer (score 1):

try the following code:

```
import shutil, sys; shutil.copy(sys.argv[0], sys.argv[2])
```

Answer (score 1):

He answers this below in the section "Common Student Questions":

> **No way you can make this one line!**
>
> That ; depends ; on ; how ; you ; define ; one ; line ; of ; code.

Answer (score 1):

```
output = open(to_file, 'w')
output.write(indata)
```

can be written as

```
open(to_file, 'w').write(indata)
```

Answer (score 1):

Had some fun with this one.  In answering this I was looking for a solution that preserved the functionality, used the file commands the exercise was about and did not use ";" to combine lines.  Closest I could come is

```
open(input("Out?: "), 'w').write(open(input("In?: ")).read())
```

Not quite the same functionality as it prompts for input rather than taking command line. But a single line that gets the job done while using the file commands in the exercise and avoiding concatenating lines using semi colon.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Kiwi (and whomever else finds this!),

I'm on the same exercise and I believe I've cracked it.

There are two possible readings of Shaw's "I could make this one line long" tease.

1. He could make the Python script one line long, upon importing all the necessary commands from the modules, e.g `from sys import argv`, etc.
2. He could copy the contents of one file to another in one line using the command line.

I personally think he means the latter, but I will explain both solutions for the sake of learning!

**The first (Long) solution:**
You must acknowledge that you require the `import`x `from` y lines in the Python file, otherwise `argv` and `exist` won't work because they will only have been implicitly referenced, i.e. you haven't made it clear to Python that you want to use these functions.

The next thing to do is delete all irrelevant code, with irrelevant being code that is written for the benefit of the user, i.e. `print`, `raw_input()`, `len()`, etc.

If you do this, you will be left with:

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

script, from_file, to_file = argv

indata = open(from_file).read()

out_file = open(to_file, 'w')
out_file.write(indata)

out_file.close()
in_file.close()
```

To make this even shorter, you can begin nesting the variables and function in one another. This is the same principle as in maths when you could define a function and then substitute the variable representing that function into another function.

For example:

```
y = x + 3
z = y, which is essentially z = (x + 3)
```

If you work this through, you can simplify the code down to:

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

script, from_file, to_file = argv

(open(to_file, 'w').write(open(from_file).read()))
```

You can then use lots of `;` to link up all the lines of code and vio-la you're done.

**Note:** You don't need to close the files, as you did in the original, as Python will automatically close them upon executing the script.

**The second (Short) solution:**

If you look at his 'What You Should See' section, he uses cat in the terminal. This is short for concatenation, which is a means of connecting strings together. If you combine it with > you can overwrite the contents of one file with another in one line:

```
cat from_file.txt > to_file.txt
```

That's it. One line that will take the contents of one file and put it into another.

Of course, both solutions aren't perfect, as the first isn't truly one line and the second doesn't even use Python!

Feedback appreciated, I only started doing this two days ago...

Answer (score 0):

Cutting away everything you don't need, all the 'features you don't need' as Zed puts it, and you get one line. It's even less than 80 characters in length, can't get much more 'pythonic' than that!

from sys import argv; s, f, t = argv; (open(t, 'w').write(open(f).read()))

Answer (score 0):

All he is saying is that you can use a semicolon to put two lines onto one line and have it run

```
in_file = open(from_file);  indata = in_file.read()
```

You could do that with the whole piece of code if you wanted to

Answer (score 0):

I'm also doing the same book online.  I tried this, and it worked:

```
open(to_file, 'w').write(open(from_file).read())
```

In other words, I opened the file I was copying to in the write mode and then inserted the contents of the file I was copying from, after opening and reading it, into the write function.  I checked my files and it worked. Yay!

Answer (score 0):

The below line worked for me:

```
open(to_file, 'w').write(open(from_file).read())
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a hint within the Common Student Questions section:

> "No way you can make this one line!
> That ; depends ; on ; how ; you ; defi ne ; one ; line ; of ; code."

Note: This is clearly not best practice and difficult to read.

```
from sys import argv
script, from_file, to_file = argv
in_file = open(from_file); indata = in_file.read(); out_file = open(to_file, 'w'); out_file.write(indata); out_file.close(); in_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

This the most reduced code that preserves the ui maybe there is other better solutions.

From 21 lines down to 8 lines of code.

Before:

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

script, from_file, to_file = argv

print("Copying from %s to %s" % (from_file, to_file))

# we could do these two on one line too, how?
input = open(from_file)
indata = input.read()

print("The input file is %d bytes long" % len(indata))

print("Does the output file exist? %r" % exists(to_file))
print("Ready, hit RETURN to continue, CTRL-C to abort.")
#raw_input()

output = open(to_file, 'w')
output.write(indata)

print("Alright, all done.")
```

To:

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

script, from_file, to_file = argv

output = open(to_file, 'w').write(open(from_file).read())

print("""Copying from %s to %s\nThe input file is %d bytes long\nDoes the output file exist? %r\nReady, hit RETURN to continue, CTRL-C to abort.\nAlright, all done.""" % (from_file, to_file, len(open(from_file).read()), exists(to_file)))
```