# Extra credit 3, learn python the hard way Exercise 17

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Learn Python the Hard Way Exercise 17 Extra Question(S)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561279/learn-python-the-hard-way-exercise-17-extra-questions)

In this exercise I have to rewrite the code in one line.  I tried to write the lines of code like this(from sys import argv,from os.path import exists) but it gives me a syntax error. So, I'm very curious, how can I write this exercise on one line?

Here is the code from the book:

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

script, from_file, to_file = argv

print "Copying from %s to %s" % (from_file, to_file)


indata = open(from_file).read()

print "The input file is %d bytes long" % len(indata)

print "Does the output file exist? %r" % exists(to_file)
print "Ready, hit RETURN to continue, CTRL-C to abort."
raw_input()

output = open(to_file, 'w')
output.write(indata)

print "Alright, all done."


output.close()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Learn Python the Hard Way Exercise 17 Extra Question(S)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3561279/1132524). See [Alex Martelli answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3561437/1132524) for the one line solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `;` to separate statements instead of `,`.

---

I don't think the purpose of the exercise is simply concatenating the lines and separating them with a semicolon. You should try to actually minimize the code.

For example:

```
output = open(to_file, 'w')
output.write(indata)

print "Alright, all done."

output.close()
```

Can be replaced with:

```
with open(to_file, 'w') as output: output.write(indata)
```