# Python: How can I make this code one line long?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I make this code one line long? I am doing an exercise on the "Learn Python the Hard Way" and the instructor says that he could write this code in one line only.

```
 #Argv is imported from the system library
    from sys import argv
    #Exists is imported from the os.path library
    from os.path import exists
    #script, from_file, and to_file are assigned to argv
    #to ask for the user's input upon start of the program
    script, from_file, to_file = argv
    #This will print the following string
    print "Copying from %s to %s" % (from_file, to_file)
    #Open the wanted file is assigned to in_file automatically
    #opens as read only. In_file.read is assigned to indata
    in_file = open(from_file)
    indata = in_file.read()
    #The string will printed and %d will be replaced by the len of indata
    print "The input file is %d bytes long" % len(indata)
    #The string below will be printed and will True/False whether the file exists
    #It will ask the user if he/she wants to continue
    print "Does the output file exist? %r" % exists(to_file)
    print "Ready, hit RETURN to continue, CTRL-C to abort."
    raw_input()
    #It will open the to file as write mode and assign it to out_file
    #The text document file will be re-written by the text from indata
    out_file = open(to_file, "w")
    out_file.write(indata)
    #The string below will be printed
    print "Alright, all done."
    #The program will now close both files because we are done using them
    out_file.close()
    in_file.close()
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the exercise explain?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Learn Python the Hard Way Exercise 17 Extra Question(S)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561279/learn-python-the-hard-way-exercise-17-extra-questions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is:

```
import shutil
import sys

script, from_file, to_file = sys.argv
shutil.copy(from_file, to_file)
```

To do the actual copying. The rest of your code is just comments and print statements.

Comment: I have another question since it doesn't let me more than one question before 90 minutes have passed. I am new to Python, why is my program printing the value of h sixty times instead of (h*60) which is what I want it to do? Thank you! :)

    def practice(hours):
     print "You have been practicing for %s hours" % hours
     minutes = 60 * h
     print "You have been practicing for %s minutes" % minutes
    h = raw_input("How many hours did you spend practicing?" )
    practice(h)

Comment: Because `h` is a string and not a number.

Answer (score 1):

```
indata = open(from_file).read()
```

probably [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561279/learn-python-the-hard-way-exercise-17-extra-questions)

Answer (score 1):

```
from sys import argv; script, from_file, to_file = argv; out_file = open(to_file, 'w').write(open(from_file).read())
```

^ that's a one-line.

; is useful. (Zed Shaw mentions this in the "Common Student Questions" section of "Learning Python the hard way")

What I did was simplifying everything to the point that you don't need the same variable mentioned twice.